# Android SQLite query ContentProvider Case Statement syntax

Tags: android, sqlite, case

I am receiving an error when I run this query, any clue what my syntax error is?

```
final Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
Provider.GAME_URI, new String[]{"CASE WHEN " +DBHelper.COLUMN_CRE_USER + " = " + preferences.getInt(LoginScreen.ID, 0) + " THEN (" + DBHelper.COLUMN_CRE_PTS + " AS you AND " + DBHelper.COLUMN_CON_PTS + " AS them) ELSE (" + DBHelper.COLUMN_CON_PTS + " AS you AND " + DBHelper.COLUMN_CRE_PTS + " AS them)"},"turn = ?",
new String[] { preferences.getInt(LoginScreen.ID, 0) + ""}, null);
```

> 04-24 19:57:48.345: E/AndroidRuntime(18775): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AS": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT CASE WHEN createduser = 112 THEN (createdplayerpts AS you AND connectedplayerpts AS them) ELSE (connectedplayerpts AS you AND createdplayerpts AS them) FROM game WHERE (turn = ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN createduser = 112 THEN createdplayerpts ELSE connectedplayerpts END AS you,
    CASE WHEN createduser = 112 THEN connectedplayerpts ELSE createdplayerpts END AS them
FROM 
    game WHERE (turn = ?)
```